# State pattern in the domain could affect service layer badly

Tags: .net, rest, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

We have N-layered application which we try to design with DDD in mind. The app is exposed as a REST service.
We have a domain entity that utilizes state pattern. The interface for state is like this

```
interface IDomainObjectState
{
    void SetPassed();
    void SetFailed();
    void SetIncomplete();
    void Pause();
    void Block();
}
```

This entity also has Status field. The state methods beginning with "Set" are supposed to change this field if object's state allows.

While this allows us to have rather clean code in Domain, it's pain at the Service layer: we use separate REST resource to change the Status of the entity (say, we `PUT /result` to do this). The problem that makes me cry is that we have `switch` on the new status that came in DTO to select one of those three methods (and the only way to do that is in Application layer, I guess).

Is it good idea to merge three "Set*" methods into one? Please suggest another refactoring if not!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it good idea to merge three "Set*" methods into one?

It isn't a good idea if the only motivation is to streamline integration with a HTTP interface. IMO, a switch statement isn't terrible because it is part of adapter/ACL code which is generally straightforward, easily tested and doesn't require a great design. Ideally, the HTTP adapter would call an application service which encapsulates the behavior at hand. If you wanted to, you could create a mapping between specific HTTP resource/verb combinations and application service methods, however this doesn't add much value overall.